# TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: powershell, blockchain, truffle

So basically I am just getting started with Truffle and I have created my first Solidity code, which looks like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;
contract HelloWorld
{

function SayHello() internal pure returns (string)
{
    return ("Hello World!");
}

}
```

I then opened Powershell and ran the following command: testrpc Than I compiled and migrated my code using "truffle" compile and "truffle migrate"

The problems started occurring when I opened "truffle console" and did this, giving me an error at the end:

```
PS C:\Users**\MetaCoin> truffle console

truffle(development)> var hw

undefined

truffle(development)> HelloWorld.deployed().then(function(deployed){hw=deployed});

undefined

truffle(development)> hw.SayHello.call()

TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

truffle(development)>
```

Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Not familiar with Truffle but from the looks of it your variable "hw" is never assigned a value, so hw.SayHello() is not a valid reference

Comment: @trebleCode Thanks for the suggestion. What do you think it should be? If I say that var hw = 1; it still doesn't help with the call error

Comment: I'll have to download truffle and tinker with your code. If this is being run in powershell, you can check the values from the most recent error record like this

`$Error[0] | Get-Member` and check whichever subproperties might show where your problem lies

Comment: should I run the $Error[0] | Get-Member in the truffle console? Becuase this gives me: ReferenceError: $Error is not defined

Comment: @trebleCode Cheers for help tho.